# How can i write the string to the text file in my resource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, text

I have a `textfile.txt` in my project resource, I want to write a string overwrite my text resource file. How can i know the path of my resource or how can i write to it ?  I have try to use this code but it didn't work

```
IResourceWriter writer = new ResourceWriter(Properties.Resources.myresourcefile);

// Adds resources to the resource writer.
writer.AddResource("String 1", "First String");

writer.Generate();
// Writes the resources to the file or stream, and closes it.
writer.Close();
```

Comment: Do you get an exception? What is the value of `Properties.Resources.myresourcefile`?

Comment: It seems you want to rewrite at runtime a resource that is embeded in your exe(or dll): this would mean changing the executable binary file.
If this is what you want... simply don't do it.
Use applicationSettings for this, maybe encryipting the text if you need to keep that data secret.

ResourceWriter is expected to write in a stream or an external file.

Comment: @TimSchmelter it seem like it appear a text in my text file  it didn't get a path or location

Comment: @GianPaolo are there another ways to use the text file to read and overwrite the file. Can u give me more information please ?

Comment: The resource you are getting (at runtime) with `Properties.Resources.myresourcefile` is something is "embeded" in the executable at compile time, so it's not something you can change at runtime.
It's not a file: it's something that was a file when you inserted it in your Visual studio project, and that compiler translated in 0 and 1 inside your myapplication.exe 
It seems you are talking about setting: have a default value in your app.config, and change it at runtime according to your needs

Comment: @GianPaolo so i should make the text file and pack it with my project when i make a setup but my file had secret information . how can i hide my file if i make the text file out side my resource?

Comment: save within settings but crypted somehow, and decrypt it at runtime

Comment: can u suggest me some method please? ;D @GianPaolo

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do, instead of "hiding" the data, is to save and load your data in encrypted way, so anyone accessing data cannot understand them.

For encrypting /decrypting a string, have a look at this
http://remy.supertext.ch/2011/01/simple-c-encryption-and-decryption/

You can store your encrypted data in application settings.
to read application settings:

```
enctryptedStringSaved = Properties.Settings.Default.SecretString; //SecretString == whatever name you choose in your settings
```

to write and save:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.SecretString = someEncryptedString;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: thank you very much. i'll try it on monday. I'll tell you for result. ^^ @Gian Paolo